# Проблема с JQuery UI Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

Всем привет! Прошу помощи, уже всю голову сломал, навык минимальный в JQ, но как только не изощрялся, в общем дело в том, что у меня не получается по нажатию на элемент изменить значение ui.value, то есть  сам ползунок перемещается, а значение  ui.value остается прежним, прошу к Вашему вниманию код:

```
$( ".slider-range" ).slider({
range: "min",
min: 0,
max: 4,
value: 2,
step: 1,
slide: function( event, ui ) {

 var steps = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
 var step;

  step = ui.value;
 if(steps.indexOf(step)===-1) return false;

  if(!ui.value) {
    document.getElementById('message').style.display = 'none';
  }else{
    document.getElementById('message').style.display = 'block';
   }
 } });

$('#five').click(function(){
  $(".slider-range").slider({
    value: 1
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы в обработчике click по новой инициализируете слайдер. Попробуйте устанавливать значение так `$(".slider-range").slider("value", 1);`

```js
$( "#slider" ).slider({
  range: 'min',
  min: 0,
  max: 4,
  value: 2,
  step: 1,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    console.log('В обработчике slide: ' + ui.value);
  }
});

$('#link').click(function() {
  $( "#slider" ).slider('value', 1);
  console.log('После клика по ссылке: ' + $( "#slider" ).slider('value'));
});
```

```css
#slider {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="slider"></div>
<a href="#" id="link">Click me</a>
```

Как видно из примера, value слайдера меняется.

Comment: Это ничего не меняет, тоже самое.

Comment: Я сейчас напишу в ответ, посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: Опция value вообще странные значения передает

Answer (score 0):

Павел, попробуйте вывести так, у них значения изначально разные

```
console.log('Параметр ui.value: ' + ui.value);
console.log('Опиция value: ' + $( ".slider-range" ).slider('value'));
```

Comment: голову сломал, сам задал вопрос, сам себе ответил - а обращается к Павлу О_о

Comment: В комментарий не получалось отправить код, поэтому я добавил ответ